2008 GMC sierra 1500 salvaged title
What should i do next ? Truck is a salvaged title a 2008 Gmc sierra 1500  quit starting no crank no start. Then ran fine a week later no crank, no start, starter relay  good, starter good, solenoid good, battery good. Replaced neutral safety. Gone through wiring system and checked for shorts. Ran computer diagnostic says wrong vin number when i tried to programming new key.  Had an extremely difficult time registering vehicle bought from third party that was selling to flip it from a dealer. Salvaged title. Truck ran great. Suddenly no crank no start diagnostic says wrong vin?
